# How to resize Android Widget?

Tags: android-widget, widget

I'm new with Widget development..I managed to built a widget, which could not be resized..I want it to be like - users manage to resize it according to themselves...Can someone tell me on how to make it possible?

Thanks friends.

Answer (score 2):

The "android:resizeMode" tag in AppWidgetProviderInfo specifies whether a user can resize the widget vertically, horizontally, both, or neither.

The documentation can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData

Answer (score 2):

In AppWidgetProviderInfo.xml

```
android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
```

//for resizing horizontal and vertical resizing of widget

or

```
android:resizeMode="none"
```

//for disabling resize of widget